# Ubuntu QML Alarm not working properly

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I've been trying to create a simple app capable of setting system alarm. But although I can see the set alarm at correct time in the *event list* under my clock indicator (on desktop), it doesn't notify me at all.

If I create a new alarm at the minute relevant for the previous alarm while the old one is still visible in the *event list*, the old one suddenly notifies me (notificaton + sound). I am not playing with any alarm lists, I only want one alarm to be set at a time, but I want to be able to unset alarm that is in progress. It works fine, again until the current time equals the alarm time (rounded to minutes) when removing alarm logically doesn't work, as it's time format is "Tue 2013-09-17 10:56:00" (seconds always to zero), so it is already passed during that minute, but it is still visible in the *event list* (ok, it belongs to that minute) and it notifies me if I set a new alarm (this is what I don't understand).

So to sum it up:

- Setting an alarm does not work properly, I can see it in the list but it does not notify me at all (not even when the minute passes, it just disappears from the *event list*).
- If its time equals current time (in minutes) and if I set new alarm at that time, the old one suddenly wakes up and notifies me.

  - Another odd thing is that when I do that, there is a full date shown for the old playing alarm in the *event list*, like "Tue 10:56" or "09-17 10:56", while if I set a new alarm, only time with no date is displayed, like "10:56".

Even the example on Ubuntu Developer web doesn't work:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.Alarm/

Here is my partially modified code suffering from the same bug:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1
import Ubuntu.Components.Pickers 0.1

MainView {
    objectName: "mainView"
    applicationName: "com.ubuntu.developer.username.alarmtest"
    useDeprecatedToolbar: false

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        title: i18n.tr("Simple")

        Alarm{
            id: alarm
            onStatusChanged: {
                if(status == Alarm.Ready) {
                    button.text = "Set Alarm";
                }
            }
        }

        Column {
            spacing: units.gu(1)
            Row {
                spacing: units.gu(1)
                Label {
                    id: date
                    text: "Date:"
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                DatePicker {
                    id: datePicker
                    date: new Date()
                    mode: "Hours|Minutes"
                    onDateChanged: {
                        var pickerDate = datePicker.date;
                        pickerDate.setSeconds(0);
                        datePicker.date = pickerDate;
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    id: button
                    text: "Set Alarm";
                    onClicked: {
                        if ((alarm.operation > Alarm.NoOperation) && (alarm.operation < Alarm.Reseting)) {
                            reset();
                        }
                        else {
                            alarm.date = new Date(datePicker.date);
                            alarm.message = "My alarm";
                            alarm.save();
                            if (alarm.error != Alarm.NoError)
                                print("Error saving alarm, code: " + alarm.error + " at time " + alarm.date);
                            text = "Unset Alarm";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my question is, is it normal that it doesn't work or am I doing something wrong? Thank you very much for any help as I am currently completely lost in here. I was exploring the stock clock app alarm stuff, trying to modify official example code and it didn't help - it never works for me. On desktop Ubuntu 14.10 it is buggy and on my Ubuntu Tablet my app freezes if I try to set a new alarm after the old one was completed or removed.